# Keyboard.metrics, height is undefined

Tags: react-native

How can I heck for the keyboad height and use a ternary in my syle object?

I current get the error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'height)

```
  const ContainerStyles = {
    ...styles.container,
    backgroundColor: colors.WHITE,
    borderColor: colors.VERYLIGHTGREY,
    ...(Keyboard.metrics && Platform.OS === 'android'
      ? { paddingTop: Keyboard.metrics().height }
      : { paddingTop: 20 }),
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In React Native, you can dynamically check for the keyboard height and use a ternary operator to conditionally set the paddingTop in your style object. However, you need to make sure that you handle the case when Keyboard.metrics is undefined. Here's is your updated code**

```
const ContainerStyles = {
      ...styles.container,
      backgroundColor: colors.WHITE,
      borderColor: colors.VERYLIGHTGREY,
      ...(Keyboard.metrics && Platform.OS === 'android' && Keyboard.metrics.height
        ? { paddingTop: Keyboard.metrics.height }
        : { paddingTop: 20 }),
    };
```